# Creating Nacl Cryptography library project in Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I want to create an Eclipse project of the NaCl cryptographic library. I have installed it using the commands mentioned on the website, but I don't know how should I properly include all those files in my eclipse project so that I can use it to develop my own main function.

Can anyone help me on this? The githut repository is located at [Nacl Github](https://github.com/jeremywohl/nacl) and the project installation details are available at [Nacl Install](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/install.html)

I am completely new to this and hence have no idea. If you need any further information, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.